# Is it possible to position background image + have gradient background using CSS?

Tags: css, background, webkit

I'm trying to have some padding around the background image which is position to the right in the element, the element also has a gradient background.

I've tried using `background-origin` to position the image, but that would shift the background gradient as well.

Here's my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/th3Q6/

#### Note

- This only needs to work for Webkit based browsers.
- No additional wrapper around element.
- Element width is fluid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works...

```
a:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    width: 25px;
    height: 28px;
    margin: -5px -8px;
    float: right;
    background: url(http://i.min.us/jc808I.png) no-repeat;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/ZXMBz/).

It won't work in older IEs, but you only want WebKit support, so you're in luck. :)

Comment: No, the element is of fluid width.
I could do the image transparent faux padding, but was hoping there's other way of doing it without going down that path.